# livedata is not updating when SELECT COUNT

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using Room database.

I have a case where I want to show number of unread messages to the user.

I've created SQL QUERY

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(${Notification.COLUMN_ID_LOCAL}) FROM ${Notification.TABLE_NAME} WHERE ${Notification.COLUMN_IS_READ} = :arg0")
    fun getUnreadedNotificationsCount(unread: Boolean = false): LiveData<Int>
```

Changes of the column `Notification.COLUMN_IS_READ` don't propagate to update my `LiveData<Int>`

This case is not handled or is it a bug of Room Library?

**EDIT:** 
***please close this question***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's turn out I've provided different INSTANCES of my DataBaseRoomService,
By configuring Dagger to provide the same instance it stared working

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44958478/2163045