# Observing ViewModel LiveData from fragments without intermediary transformation variable

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I'm following the MVVM architecture in my android app. (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide). All of my repository function returns a **NetworkBoundResource** object. You can read more about this design implementation from the jetpack guide link, or view the example project from google [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/88747993139224a4bb6dbe985adf652d557de621/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt)

In this particular problem, I'm trying to re-fetch information over the network when I pull down on the screen.

**Current working implementation**

Fragment listener (triggered when screen pulled down)

```kotlin
binding.refresh.setOnRefreshListener {
    profileViewModel.refreshUserProfile()
}
```

Then in my ViewModel I have a MutableLiveData that updates value on this function call

```kotlin
private val _refresh = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

fun refreshUserProfile() {
    _refresh.value = true
}
```

And when `_refresh.value` changes, it triggers `switchMap`

```kotlin
val currentUserProfile: LiveData<Resource<UserProfile>> = _refresh.switchMap {
    if (it) {
        repository.getCurrentUserProfile(_username.value.toString())
    } else {
        AbsentLiveData.create()
    }
}
```

Repository function

```kotlin
fun getCurrentUserProfile(username: String): LiveData<Resource<UserProfile>> {
    return object : NetworkBoundResource<UserProfile, UserProfile>(AppExecutors.getInstance()) {
        override fun saveCallResult(item: UserProfile) {
            userProfileDao.update(item)
        }
        override fun shouldFetch(data: UserProfile?): Boolean {
            return true
        }
        override fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<UserProfile> {
            return userProfileDao.load(username)
        }
        override fun createCall(): LiveData<ApiResponse<UserProfile>> {
            return networkService.userProfileService.getUserProfileAsync(
                token,
                username
            )
        }
    }.asLiveData()
}
```

And then back at my fragment, I have an observer on this `currentUserProfile` ViewModel variable

```kotlin
profileViewModel.currentUserProfile.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { userProfileResult ->
    when (userProfileResult.status) {...}
})
```

**What I am trying to do**

I would like to skip the step where I'm setting `_refresh.value = true`. And instead observe the repository function directly like this:

```kotlin
val currentUserProfile: LiveData<Resource<UserProfile>> = 
    repository.getCurrentUserProfile(_username.value.toString())
```

But this implementation will not trigger the observer in the fragment.

**Question**
I don't quite understand why I wasn't able to trigger observer with my second implementation. And I'm also unsure if my initial implementation is even optimal or correct. I would appreciate any sort of feedback especially if you are familiar with this type of design.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems in the past & most of the time it was related to two things:

1. `dao` instance to insert/update was not same as `dao` instance of observing the livedata.
2. My `livedata` object was wrapped in some other livedata & returned. In short it wasn't the same `livedata` instance that `dao` returned.

You can log the instance & check if it's the same. It needs to be singleton. If you're using any kind of dependency injection tool (e.g Dagger) then checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44958478/9715339

My guess is that in your case it's most likely second case. As your `livedata` `userProfileDao.load` is being wrapped in `NetworkBoundResource.asLiveData()` & if you look at the code of `NetworkBoundResource.result` it's a `MediatorLiveData`.
so you're not actively listening to the same live data being returned by `userProfileDao`.

Just for the sake of confirming this is the issue You can try listening to the direct `livedata` being returned from `userProfileDao.load(username)` . Create a method in your repository with & see.

You can try digging in that direction more.

Comment: I'm not using any dependency injection tool. I know for sure that the room database is a singleton but I'm not sure if my DAO is one. I have since changed my implementation to use Flow instead of LiveData and I don't have any problems with observing the data anymore. So I want to rule out the DAO as being the problem. Thanks for replying.